# Why does the unset query not delete the specified field in mongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

The query I run here produces a blank (no number, basically nothing) in the mongo shell interface:

```
> db.classrooms.update( { "c_type" : { $exists : true } }, { $unset : { "c_type" : 1 } }, false, true);
```

Also, I checked the collection rows that should have had c_type removed, but they still exist.

I am basically trying to delete a column/field in my collection with the unset command.  Is there something wrong with my syntax?

Thank you!

Comment: Your syntax seems fine; in fact, your example seems to work fine for me :).  I tried with simple values for c_type as well as embedded arrays and documents.  Are you sure you are in the right `db` when you run the update?  What version of MongoDB are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Further to my comment, here's the example I tested:

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.0.6
connecting to: test

> db.classrooms.insert({"example": "field", "c_type" : "Open"});
> db.classrooms.insert({"example": "array", "c_type" : ['Available']});
> db.classrooms.insert({"example": "obj",   "c_type" : {'Booked' : 'Yes'}});

> db.classrooms.find()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("502abd4a332f362f58906683"),
    "example" : "field",
    "c_type" : "Open"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("502abd4e332f362f58906684"),
    "example" : "array",
    "c_type" : [
        "Available"
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("502abd53332f362f58906685"),
    "example" : "obj",
    "c_type" : {
        "Booked" : "Yes"
    }
}

> db.classrooms.update(
   { "c_type" : { $exists : true } },
   { $unset : { "c_type" : 1 } }, 
   false,  // upsert
   true);  // update multiple records

> db.classrooms.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("502abd4a332f362f58906683"), "example" : "field" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("502abd4e332f362f58906684"), "example" : "array" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("502abd53332f362f58906685"), "example" : "obj" }
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.  Basically I had to double quote `$exists` and `$unset`:

```
> db.classrooms.update( { "c_type" : { "$exists" : true } }, { "$unset" : { "c_type" : 1 } }, false, true);
```

Comment: What version of MongoDB are you using?

Comment: How do I find that out?  When I go to the shell it shows `MongoDB Shell Version: 2.0.4`

Comment: Try: `db.serverStatus().version`

Comment: The version that returned was 2.0.4

Comment: Hrm .. I tried same with MongoDB 2.0.4 shell (OS X) and couldn't reproduce your error.  A cut & paste of the update() without double quotes around the MongoDB operators works fine.

Comment: Could there be something else I'm missing?